# Outlook Web hook Subscription

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am working with Outlook Webhook Subscriptions and working on QA server.

According to the Microsoft Graph documentation, we need to send the request to get the webhook notification. I am using Python 3 request module for this.

I am sending the following data but getting the error. I can't figure out where I am going wrong in the process.

```
url="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions"
header={
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization':"Bearer "+ "valid access token"
}

data={
    "changeType": "created,updated",
    "notificationUrl": "https://qa.example.com/get_webhook",
    "resource": "/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
    "expirationDateTime": "2018-12-11T11:00:00.0000000Z"
}

response=requests.post(url, headers=header, data=data)
```

After executing the above lines I am getting the following <400> response

```
'{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "BadRequest",\r\n    "message": 
 "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type 
 header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.",\r\n    
 "innerError": {\r\n      "request-id": "3a15ba2f-a055-4f33-a3f8- 
 f1f40cdb2d64",\r\n      "date": "2018-12-10T06:51:32"\r\n    }\r\n  
 }\r\n}'
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with what you've posted. Can you share with us the captured request body and header from a tool like Fiddler or Charles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To post as JSON, you need to `json` property rather than the `data` property (i.e. `json={"key": "value"}`:

```
url="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions"
header={
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization':"Bearer "+ "valid access token"
}

data={
    "changeType": "created,updated",
    "notificationUrl": "https://qa.example.com/get_webhook",
    "resource": "/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
    "expirationDateTime": "2018-12-11T11:00:00.0000000Z"
}

response=requests.post(url, headers=header, json=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import json
response=requests.post(url, headers=header, data=json.dumps(data))
```